# Derive the formula and its error from the basic rule $B(f: c,d)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I understand Taylor series, for example I know the Taylor expansion for $f(a+bh)$ where $h \approx 0$ would be

$$f(a+bh) = f(a) + bhf'(a) + b^2 h^2 f''(a)/2 + \cdots$$

But I have a problem that has 2 constants, both $c$ and $d$ and it's asking for the basic rule. I'm not sure what a basic rule is, but I would assume it would be in the form $f(a+bh)$ Am I correct in this thinking?

In which case, what would the basic form look like for the Taylor series in the following problem?

[image]

Furthermore, it asks about a composite rule. Would this be in the form of a difference quotient?

Comment: what exactly fo you have to find Taylor expansion for? $f(a + bh + ck + dj)$?

Comment: @gt6989b that's kind of my question too. I don't understand how to handle the `(f: c,d)`  as apposed to something like `(f: b)`

Comment: i see. you need 2 endpts for the interval of integration, so use $(c+d)/2$ in your std formula instead of $b$...